# The self-coupling constant for the Higgs mechanism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking, higgs

I have a few questions about the parameter $\lambda$ in the Higgs-Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}_H=(D_\mu \phi)^\dagger D_\mu \phi + \mu^2\phi^\dagger\phi-\lambda(\phi^\dagger\phi)^2$$

1. Is it possible to measure it *directly*?
2. Does it absolute value have a meaning? It relates to the self-interaction of the Higgs boson (?), but can one compare this number with something else?
3. Before the mass of the Higgs was measured, did one expect a precise value for $\lambda$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters in the Lagrangian determine how strong an interaction is. That is their meaning. They can be compared with other parameters of the same mass dimension (for the case of $\lambda$ it can be compared with other parameters that are dimensionless). For example in QED we have the electron-photon term,
\begin{equation}
eA_\mu \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi
\end{equation}
The parameter $e$ is dimensionless and can be compared with $\lambda$ from the self-coupling.

The questions is measurement is a little bit subtle due to the need to renormalize our theories which I presume you are not very familiar with. If you are only doing calculation at tree-level then you can avoid this complication and you can measure the parameter directly.

This can be done by doing $\phi \phi \rightarrow \phi \phi$ scattering  (though in practice its done in a more convenient way). The cross-section for this collision is (this is straight forward to show in QFT) 
\begin{equation}
\sigma= \frac{\lambda^2}{32\pi E^2}
\end{equation}
where $E$ is the energy of the incoming Higgs. Thus if you have a Higgs collider running at a [Luminosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_%28scattering_theory%29) (a property of a collider that is typically well known), ${\cal L}$ then the number of Higgs-Higgs to Higgs-Higgs events you see per unit time is,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dN}{dt}=\frac{\lambda^2}{32\pi E^2} {\cal L}
\end{equation}
Thus by measuring number of events and knowing the energy and luminosity of your incoming beams you can extract $\lambda$.

Lastly, regarding the precise value for $\lambda$. In general it could be anything at all, but we typically expect such numbers to be within an order of magnitude of $1$ (otherwise we say a theory is unnatural).

Comment: Why is it expected to be of magnitude 1? What does it mean exactly for a theory to be fine-tuned, it seems a rather strange name... Secondly what is the value of e for QED is dimensionless parameter, doesn't it correspond to the elementary charge, which isn't dimensionless ?

Comment: Sorry, I mispoke. I should have said unnatural, not fine-tuned (I changed it now). We think of parameters in the Lagrangian as being randomly assigned by Nature with a distribution centered around $1$. The idea behind this is that $1$ and $0$ are the only unitless numbers with any fundamental meaning, but $0$ removes the interaction so if a parameter is close to zero there is no reason it should be there in the first place. There are huge discussions now with the LHC not finding new particles about the validity of this idea (though it has worked very well in the past!)

Comment: The $e$ is the Lagrangian is not the electric charge from electromagnetism but the "unitless" version of it. It is given by $ \sqrt{4\pi \alpha} \approx 0.3$